# Detecting Two Collisions in a Short Period of Time

Tags: unity-game-engine, timer, boolean

In my game, collecting one ball and missing another will only give you one point before resetting the ball. If you collect both in a short period of time, you get ten points. I've tried implementing timers, but haven't been able to get anything that works (one is not included in the below code).

```
bool oneCollected = false;
bool twoCollected = false;
public void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision) {
    if (collision.gameObject.name == "ball1" && oneCollected == false) {
        oneCollected = true;
        ball1.transform.position = new Vector2(Random.Range(-5.25f, 5.25f), 7);
        Color newColor = new Color(Random.Range(0f, 1f), Random.Range(0f, 1f), Random.Range(0f, 1f), 1f);
        count += 1;
        oneCollected = false;
    } if (collision.gameObject.name == "ball2" && twoCollected == false) {
        twoCollected = true;
        ball2.transform.position = new Vector2(Random.Range(-5.25f, 5.25f), 7);
        count += 1;
        twoCollected = false;
    } if (oneCollected && twoCollected) {
        ball1transform.position = new Vector2(Random.Range(-5.25f, 5.25f), 7);
        ball2.transform.position = new Vector2(Random.Range(-5.25f, 5.25f), 7);
        count += 10;
        oneCollected = false;
        twoCollected = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you describe the approach you took when you tried to implement your own timers? It's possible you weren't really that far off in your implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens in your code is that the value of oneCollected changes almost instantly.
You can use a Coroutine or Invoke to wait for some seconds before changing the value of oneCollected to false.

You can make a function that resets the value of oneCollected.

```
public void ResetOneCollected()
{
    oneCollected = false;
}
```

And then call it using Invoke. Inside your onCollision detection method replace the

`oneCollected = false;` with

`Invoke("ResetOneCollected", 1);` this will call ResetOneCollected method after 1 second.

---

You can take a look at the docs.

[Invoke](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Invoke.html)

[Wait for seconds using Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html)

Comment: This would work, but if you do this then when you collect the same ball twice within 1 second, the second collection will not be valid.  And since your method fires only on collision enter, if you were to keep your collection object and the ball colliding constantly, the collection would never happen unless you move off and back on the ball after the 1 second is up.

Comment: @WilliamPrevett I don't understand exactly what you mean. I should have mentioned that he has to do the same thing for the second ball. The way I see it is, he collects ball_1 -> oneCollected = true, he collects ball_2 -> twoCollected = true, then, if 1 second hasn't passed before collecting ball_2, "if (oneCollected && twoCollected)" will be true.

Comment: Lets assume you move a collection object with the mouse.  We will call that the mouse.  You collect ball 1 with the mouse.  The ball teleports..  ball1collected is true.  A timer starts for 1 second.  Before that one second is over you mouse over ball 1 again.  Nothing will happen.  1 second ends.  Ball 1 collected = false.  Mouse has not left ball 1, so no collision enter event happens.  As long as you keep mouse on ball 1, it will never be collected

Comment: @WilliamPrevett Oh, I get what you mean now. You are right, but I don't know exactly what he wants to do. I thought that he wouldn't be able to reach the ball before it is reset (the 1 second in our example has passed)

Comment: @KatK I'm glad I could help!